# PATCH in Dynamics CRM WebAPI throwing an exception Generic SQL error

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am working on an app that talks with Dynamics CRM Online 2016.

I am patching a simple object to contacts. Payload looks something like this -

```
PATCH https://<crm_tenant>.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.1/contacts(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)
{
  "emailaddress1": "test@emailaddress.com",
  "firstname": "John"
}
```

This works in POSTMAN or any other REST client. However if I do it from app which is patching approx 34 contacts in parallel (4 at a time). I am getting this exception for most of the contacts -

```
{
  "error":{
    "code":"","message":"Generic SQL error.","innererror":{
      "message":"Generic SQL error.","type":"System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]","stacktrace":"   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Execute(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode, ExecutionContext executionContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataExecutionContext.Upsert(Entity entity)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataExecutionContext.Update(Entity entity, UpdateOption updateOption)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.CrmODataServiceDataProvider.UpdateEdmEntity(CrmODataExecutionContext context, String edmEntityName, String entityKeyValue, EdmEntityObject entityObject)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OData.EntityController.PatchEntity(String entityName, String key, EdmEntityObject entityDelta)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried searching for possible solutions on internet but couldn't find any. Any help would be appreciated.

Rahul.

Comment: I know that you are saying about online byt in my on-permise environment most cases of "Generic SQL error" are, sadly to say...timeouts. Even if entity doesn't have any plugins. More concurrent things to do, more I/O saturation, more locks, higher probability of timeout.

Comment: How can we get rid of it? @pen2? Slow, throttled PATCH and POSTS?

Answer (score 1):

CRM Online doesn't allow more than 2 concurrent requests

> Throttling of concurrent calls – for Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online there is a limit of 2 concurrent ExecuteMultipleRequest executions per organization. If that limit is exceeded, a “Server Busy” fault is thrown before the first request is ever executed. For an on-premises deployment, throttling is not enabled by default. The deployment setting for this limit is ExecuteAsyncPerOrgMaxConnectionsPerServer.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863631.aspx#limitations

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that running that in parallel would cause the issue, but if you want to update a lot of records at once it might be better to use a batch request.

Here's the documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607719.aspx

I've found it a bit tricky to implement, as building the batch request is really sensitive on using the right format.

Comment: The only reason why I am not doing batching is the entity generation can be fairly complex. e.g. I create one contact and there might be another entity that has contact as lookup field. So I will be needing contactid in the later payload.

Comment: Good reason. Did you test if it's caused by running the PATCH in parallel? I know I get SQL exception errors when you run certain processes at the same time (although these are configurations, not updates to records).

Comment: I removed parallelism and it suddenly started working again. If I send requests in parallel some of the requests fail with this exception. That's sad. The errors should be graceful

Comment: I agree, if you really want performance you might want to do a batch and parse the response to get the contactid's from it. But that's some serious text parsing.